# ElasticSearch Kibana histogram chart Value_field

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, performance-testing, logstash, kibana

I have a log file which is in the following format.

timeStamp,elapsed,label,bytes,Latency

I have a filter inside my logstash with following grok parser

```
grok{
    match => ["message","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},%{NUMBER:elapsed},%{DATA:label},%{NUMBER:bytes},%{NUMBER:Latency}"]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:sss Z", "ISO8601" ]
      timezone => "UTC"
    }
```

Now I am trying to create a graph plotting timestamp vs Latency or Timestamp vs bytes.

I am trying to use the panel type as histogram and the chart value as Total or Mean, when I try to enter the Value field as Latency or elapsed, I am getting an error in elasticsearch

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.facet.FacetPhaseExecutionException: Facet [0]: (value) field [elapsed] not found
    at org.elasticsearch.search.facet.datehistogram.DateHistogramFacetParser.parse(DateHistogramFacetParser.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.facet.FacetParseElement.parse(FacetParseElement.java:93)

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.facet.FacetPhaseExecutionException: Facet [0]: (value) field [Latency] not found
    at org.elasticsearch.search.facet.datehistogram.DateHistogramFacetParser.parse(DateHistogramFacetParser.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.facet.FacetParseElement.parse(FacetParseElement.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:644)
    ... 9 more
```

This happens even though the logs do have Latency or elapsed fields.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does every single message matching your query have elapsed and Latency fields?

Comment: Are there documents in your elasticsearch instance with the appropriate mapping? Did you remember to convert latency and bytes to numeric values in your logstash conf file?

Comment: @MagnusBäck yes. Each one of the logs has elapsed and Latency Fields

Comment: @Roman I did try that, but later took off for debugging. Any suggestions on how I should implement. I mutate and convert functions inside the filter part of the Logstash conf file. 

Here is a sample of the log file 

timeStamp,elapsed,label,bytes,Latency
2014-11-18T18:36:27.166+0530,2578,page_1,54185,1648
2014-11-18T18:36:26.959+0530,2447,page_1,54185,1542
2014-11-18T18:36:30.451+0530,788,page_2,4334,297
2014-11-18T18:36:30.442+0530,804,page_2,4334,314

Comment: This is the error I am getting when I search for elapsed or Latency
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData
       at org.elasticsearch.search.facet.datehistogram.DateHistogramFacetParser.parse(DateHistogramFacetParser.java:197)
       at org.elasticsearch.search.facet.FacetParseElement.parse(FacetParseElement.java:93)
       at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:644)
       ... 9 more